# Can tell sign of derivative through observing numerator and denominator limits?

Tags: derivatives

Say a derivative is differentiable in the interval $x \in [a,b]$

The derivative of the limit at $f(b)$ is $\lim\limits_{x \to b^+}\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}$

If we can show that $\lim\limits_{x \to b^+}f(x)-f(b)$ and  $\lim\limits_{x \to b^+}x-b$ both converges to $0$ from above, then is $f'(b)\geq 0$?

Comment: Do you think that $x-b$ can converge to $0$ from above when $x\to b$?

Comment: Sorry typo! Fixed it

Comment: How do you define "a function converges to $0$ from above"? I don't think I've seen such a concept before.

Comment: The function $y = 1/x$ converges to $0$ from above as x approaches positive infinity